# Separate a URL with str_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

I have two websites using WordPress: `www.exemple.com` (fr-FR) and `ca.exemple.com/fr` (fr-CA)

To avoid duplicate content on Google I have to change dynamically this meta:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CA" href="ca.exemple.com/fr/shop">
```

So when I put in `header.php` on `www.exemple.com/shop`

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CA" href="<?php echo str_replace("//", "//ca.", get_site_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" />
```

It returns:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="ca.exemple.com/shop">
```

How can I add `/fr/` between `.com` and `/shop/`?

EDIT : SOLUTION

I've made a special code that will verify if the code exist on the other page so we dont have 404 errors for nothing, here it is :

```
<?php
$alt_url = str_replace( "ca.exemple.com/fr/fr", "www.exemple.com" , get_site_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$currentz = str_replace( "ca.exemple.com/fr/fr" , "ca.exemple.com/fr" ,   get_site_url() . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$file_headers = @get_headers($alt_url);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {

}
else {
echo "<link rel=\"alternate\" hreflang=\"fr-CA\" href=\"$currentz\" />";
echo "\n";
echo "<link rel=\"alternate\" hreflang=\"fr-FR\" href=\"$alt_url\" />";
}
?>
```

Comment: That `get_site_url` can be filtered and processed with a plugin. But I don't understand the relation between the two sites. Are they using the same theme? Same WP install? Special `wp-config.php`?

Comment: different instal, same server but not the same domain (subdomain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in the string in your concatenation

```
<?php echo str_replace("//", 
          "//ca.", get_site_url() .'/fr'. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

I probably wouldn't do it like this. But that's the quick answer.

There's no need to run str_replace over the whole string.

```
 echo str_replace('//'.'//ca.',get_site_url()).'/fr'/. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Also, there are functions for [parsing urls](https://www.php.net/parse_url)

Comment: Thank you very much,
Also what would be the reverse way ? ca.exemple.com/fr/ to www.exemple.com my problem is now different, i want to remove ca. and replace it with www., and i just want to remove /fr/

Comment: You'll need to do two substitutions ... `str_replace('http://ca.','http://www.','http://ca.example.com/fr/index.html');`  and `str_replace('/fr/','','http://www.example.com/fr/index.html');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/shop';

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);


echo str_replace($path,'/fr'.$path, $url); // http://example.com/fr/shop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another string replace after your existing string replace.
For example:

```
 <?php
       $url = str_replace("//", "//ca.", "http://www.yahoo.com/shop");
       $url = str_replace(".com", ".com/fr", $url);
       echo $url;
    ?>
```

Would result in:

```
http://ca.www.yahoo.com/fr/shop
```